# Can I export stackoverflow badges to mozilla openbadge bagpack?

Tags: badge

Is there any way to export the stackoverflow badges to mozilla openbadges https://openbadges.org/ without export it mannually?

Comment: Wrong site. Questions about SO itself belong on [meta]. This site is for programming and programmers tools related questions.